# Rails, Devise, and validating email address with emojis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, character-encoding, emoji, utf8mb4

I was really behind the times, and just recently converted my MySQL (v5.7.30) database tables to support `utf8mb4` (emojis, symbols, etc). I'm using Devise 3.5.10 for user authentication in my Rails 4 app.

To validate email, I rely on [Devise's default `email_regexp`](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v3.5.10/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L31).

Since emojis are permitted in email addresses, I want to make sure I get my validation right. The current regex I'm using lets them through, and when signing up with something like `example@test.com`, in the database it's actually saved as `example@xn--test-r625f.com`.

I logged out and logged back in with `example@test.com`, and sure enough it worked. So:

1) Should I continue using the default Devise email regex to allow symbols and emoji? `/\A[^@\s]+@([^@\s]+\.)+[^@\W]+\z/`

2) Why did it save in the database with the `r625f` text instead of the actual emoji? Elsewhere in my database where an emoji appears in a `VARCHAR` field I just see it as the actual emoji.

Comment: regex email validation is not worth too much thought after you determine it looks like `local-part@domain`, and the parts don't have spaces, so  the devise regex is fine.

Comment: @dbugger Ok sounds good. Do you know anything about emojis in email addresses saving as that strange encoding?

Comment: looks like devise is doing some serialization under the covers